# XSD Schema namespace issues

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

How do I 'expect' an element to have a namespace using XSD? At this point I receive an error saying: *"Invalid content was found starting with element 'ns:person'. One of '{"":person}' is expected."*

As you can see I define the `name` attribute on the `xs:element`: "person". If I define "ns:person" as the `name` then I get an error that the name is invalid aaarghh.

**What am I missing here?**

This is the XSD (ns.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="peoples">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="person"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is the XML (peoples.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<peoples xmlns:ns="url" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ns.xsd">
<ns:person>
        <name>John</name>
</ns:person>
</peoples>
```

Comment: There are a number of errors here and I think you'd be best running through some tutorial examples - such as http://zvon.org/xxl/XMLSchemaTutorial/Output/series.html or http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp. {Errors include no namespace declarartions in instance, two namespaces required; no namespace declaration in schema, no element "name" in schema)

Comment: Sorry i left those out for readability... Of course those are present in my file. Running through a validator gives me the error as described.

Comment: @Ropstah: Perhaps you could edit the question and add those missing items back in, as their omission actually *hinders* readability.

Comment: I understand, but I cannot post the XSD. This would also distract from the problem I think. In this case Pangea is close i think!

Comment: @Ropstah: I'm downvoting your question because you refuse to post an example that reproduces your problem. I don't care whether or not it's the original XSD and XML - just so long as it reproduces the same problem.

Comment: You're right it didn't reproduce the problem. However I did **state** the problem? I changed the question anyhow, can anybody see the problem/solution now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the complete XSD to help you. But from the error I see and the fact that you have included "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" in your XML instance document, the problem I see is that you defined your schema with **no targetNamespace** specified but you are qualifying **person** element with a namespace prefix. Just remove "ns:" at all places in your instance document and you are all good.

Comment: I think you are right. The problem however is that I cannot remove those ns: instances (nor edit anything else in the XSD). Is there a way to allow for 'wildcard' elements or elements qualified by regex?

Comment: I am afraid pre-processing of the XML to remove "ns:", before giving it to the XML parser is the only options. But are you sure you will only get xml's that have "ns" as the prefix? Anything can be used as the prefix name in which case you also need to know what prefix is being used before hand.

Comment: I know that the prefix 'ns' is used. There is also a xmlns:ns="url" declaration in the XML file. Is there any way of specifying the location of the corresponding XSD (for url) in the ns.xsd file?

Comment: The only way I see of fixing this is pre processing as I mentioned earlier. However I am curious why the XML is being created this way if there is an XSD already existing for it?